# Laravel loop - position items in repeated container

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a foreach loop for each event. I have just realised the main wrapper and the 3 items inside it are all the same event.

The first, second and third event should it in one wrapper. Close. Then a new main wrapper for 4, 5, 6 should open and so on..

**My initial thoughts on a solution:**

I thought maybe use:

```
@if ($loop->first)
```

Placing 'first' where primary is. ->'second' where secondary is etc. But as this is a loop, I can't statically account for 1st, 2nd, 3rd and onwards up to hundreds.

**Current Code**

```
@foreach( $events['events'] as $event )

  <!-- Product Grid -->
  <div class="flex-grid">
    <div class="flex__direction--column">
      <div class="flex__direction--row">

        <!-- 1ST ITEM -->
        <div class="item item--primary">

          <div class="a-card a-card--secondary a-card--event-template {{ $block }}__card">
            <div class="a-card__media-wrapper">
              <div class="a-card__box-content">
                <div class="a-card__date-wrapper">
                  <span class="a-card__meta a-card__date">{{ $date['0'] }}</span>
                  <span class="a-card__meta a-card__date">{{ $date['1'] }}</span>
                  <span class="a-card__meta a-card__date">{{ $date['2'] }}</span>
                </div>
              </div>
              <img class="a-card__media--image" src="http://wp3-dev.fatsomasites.com/app/uploads/sites/396/2018/04/1920x1080.jpg">
              <div class="a-card__heading-wrapper">
                <a class="a-card__media-link" href="#">
                  <h2 class="a-card__heading">
                    {{ $event['title'] }}
                  </h2>
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>

        <div class="item flex__direction--column">
          <div class="item">
            <!-- 2ND ITEM -->
            <div class="flex__direction--row">
              <div class="item item--secondary">

                <div class="a-card a-card--secondary a-card--event-template {{ $block }}__card">
                  <div class="a-card__media-wrapper">
                    <div class="a-card__box-content">
                      <div class="a-card__date-wrapper">
                        <span class="a-card__meta a-card__date">{{ $date['0'] }}</span>
                        <span class="a-card__meta a-card__date">{{ $date['1'] }}</span>
                        <span class="a-card__meta a-card__date">{{ $date['2'] }}</span>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <img class="a-card__media--image" src="http://wp3-dev.fatsomasites.com/app/uploads/sites/396/2018/04/1920x1080.jpg">
                    <div class="a-card__heading-wrapper">
                      <a class="a-card__media-link" href="#">
                        <h2 class="a-card__heading">
                          {{ $event['title'] }}
                        </h2>
                      </a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>

              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- 3RD ITEM -->
            <div class="flex__direction--row">
              <div class="item item--tertiary">

                <div class="a-card a-card--secondary a-card--event-template {{ $block }}__card">
                  <div class="a-card__media-wrapper">
                    <div class="a-card__box-content">
                      <div class="a-card__date-wrapper">
                        <span class="a-card__meta a-card__date">{{ $date['0'] }}</span>
                        <span class="a-card__meta a-card__date">{{ $date['1'] }}</span>
                        <span class="a-card__meta a-card__date">{{ $date['2'] }}</span>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <img class="a-card__media--image" src="http://wp3-dev.fatsomasites.com/app/uploads/sites/396/2018/04/1920x1080.jpg">
                    <div class="a-card__heading-wrapper">
                      <a class="a-card__media-link" href="#">
                        <h2 class="a-card__heading">
                          {{ $event['title'] }}
                        </h2>
                      </a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

@endforeach
```

This is the current output. 
[image]

What I am trying to achieve:
[image]

Comment: Wait, what? Can you explain your problem better?

Comment: @Troyer. Ok I'll try. The first event should go in the first largest box. The second event should go in the 2nd (top right box). The 3rd event in the bottom right box. Then repeat the entire thing again for the 4,5,6th events and so on. I will update the image 1 moment.

Comment: Have you considered using the Collection chunk method?  https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-chunk

Comment: @Troyer . Any thoughts? I've added a new image to explain what i am after too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is a bit quick copy paste :)
you'll sort it

```
var $counter = 0;
foreach ($sorce_array as $event) {
$counter++;
if (($counter % 3) == 1)  { 

<div class="flex-grid">
    <div class="flex__direction--column">
      <div class="flex__direction--row">
<div class="item item--primary">

          <div class="a-card a-card--secondary a-card--event-template {{ $block }}__card">
            <div class="a-card__media-wrapper">
              <div class="a-card__box-content">
                <div class="a-card__date-wrapper">
                  <span class="a-card__meta a-card__date">{{ $date['0'] }}</span>
                  <span class="a-card__meta a-card__date">{{ $date['1'] }}</span>
                  <span class="a-card__meta a-card__date">{{ $date['2'] }}</span>
                </div>
              </div>
              <img class="a-card__media--image" src="http://wp3-dev.fatsomasites.com/app/uploads/sites/396/2018/04/1920x1080.jpg">
              <div class="a-card__heading-wrapper">
                <a class="a-card__media-link" href="#">
                  <h2 class="a-card__heading">
                    {{ $event['title'] }}
                  </h2>
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
} 

If ((($counter % 3) ==2)) {
<div class="item flex__direction--column">
          <div class="item">
}

If (($counter % 3) != 1)  { 
<div class="flex__direction--row">
              <div class="item item--secondary">

                <div class="a-card a-card--secondary a-card--event-template {{ $block }}__card">
                  <div class="a-card__media-wrapper">
                    <div class="a-card__box-content">
                      <div class="a-card__date-wrapper">
                        <span class="a-card__meta a-card__date">{{ $date['0'] }}</span>
                        <span class="a-card__meta a-card__date">{{ $date['1'] }}</span>
                        <span class="a-card__meta a-card__date">{{ $date['2'] }}</span>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <img class="a-card__media--image" src="http://wp3-dev.fatsomasites.com/app/uploads/sites/396/2018/04/1920x1080.jpg">
                    <div class="a-card__heading-wrapper">
                      <a class="a-card__media-link" href="#">
                        <h2 class="a-card__heading">
                          {{ $event['title'] }}
                        </h2>
                      </a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>

              </div>
            </div>
    }

If (($counter % 3) == 0)  { 
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
}
}
```